# drag "div1" then drop into "div2" open link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

Good Day All

Please Help...

I want to drag div id="box1" into div id="box2" or div id="box3"

Then what I need help with is that "on drop" next page(link) opens.

Code:

```
    <script>
       function allowDrop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
       }

       function drag(ev) {
          ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
       }

       function drop(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
          ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
       }
    </script>


    <body>

       <div id="box1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
           <img src="images/logo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
       <h4>Box1</h4>
       </div>

       <div id="box2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
           <img src="images/entnor.png">
       <h4>Box2</h4>
       </div>   

       <div id="box3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
           <img src="images/entad.png">
       <h4>Box3</h4>
       </div>
```

a Tad new to all this still in learning process.

Johan